# How can I add entries into the MANIFEST.MF file during build-time with IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, manifest.mf

I want to add Weblogic-Application-Version: 2013-BLAH-BLAH to the manifest for deployment directly to weblogic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA can not do that automatically via its build runner. It is an IDE and not a build tool. So its build features, while decent, are limited. You have two options:

1. Manually put the version into the Manifest.MF file before building with IDEA.
2. Use a build tool such as Ant, Maven, or Gradle to build your webapp and add the entry.